# How do I force a given file to expire in the cache?

Tags: caching, browser, client

I have a feeling I should know this.

I have a web app that contains a large number of images, css and script files.

The problem I'm having is that if I update the app and one of these 'static' items has changed, I need to ensure that a browser accessing the app is using the newest version of the file.

I know I can't clear the client cache from my app so that's out.

I'm sure that I'm not the only guy to have had this issue so I thought I'd ask here. I've found lots of stuff about the server cache but nothing that obviously deals with this.

Anyone any pointers I can follow up?

-- 
Stuart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a get method at the end to make the browser think it's dynamic content that need to be updated.

For example

```
<img src="img.jpg?version=1" />
```

And just change `version` id every time you change the image. You might use this in css and javascript imported as well.

Comment: @ramdom_user That's clever. I like that.