# Elegant way to force client browsers to re-download our asp.net web app's .css and .js files (without totally disabling caching)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, caching, iis

Our asp.net web application allows our (large) .css and .js files to be cached by client browsers for faster performance.

But whenever we deploy a new version, we get phone calls from users about how the page looks messy and is full of javascript errors. It turns out, their browser didn't re-download the changed .css and .js files. Ctrl-F5 always fixes it.

Is there any way to force a re-download after upgrade deployments, without setting it not to cache (and thus slowing our application down)?

I've found this (manually changing reference to every file every deployment):
[How do I force a given file to expire in the cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443441)

and this (same thing but checksum calculation on every page load):
[Needed advice on how to implement js/css versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164677)

But surely there are more reasonable solutions than that...?

Comment: What is the solution that you reached? Can you please post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the version number in the file works well for us:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="somefile.js?v=1.0"></script>
```

As long as you change that version number each "release", the browser thinks its a new file.

You could do this by simply having a version number in a global file (like a config file or something) and then setting the variable on each script/css tag you wish.

Comment: This will work, but I have a few different master pages with a dozen of these links, this seems quite a bit of work and something easy to forget amongst all the other deployment tasks. Surely there is a better way? A setting change in ASP.NET or IIS...? A http header that IE won't flat-out ignore...?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of any other solutions that work like this. You want it to cache, but only when you update. If the file doesn't have a version with it, then there isn't much you can do.  I suppose you could have a cookie that you set after initial load that if is present, can bypass no-cache headers or something along those lines, but if you setup correctly, should be easy on each deployment to do as I mentioned above.

Comment: A Java app I am working is setup to read in a variable that is retrieved from our SVN revisions, so once we deploy, it always has a fresh version number without any changes required on our part.

Comment: When I implement this solution, I find that Chrome loads a new version of my CSS every time I refresh even if the version number never changes.  Shouldn't it only get the latest version if the number changes?

Comment: Sounds like a setting in Chrome or a bug. It should cache each script with the version number.

Comment: I don't know.  It's happening in IE as well.  This solution looks pretty popular on the web, so I'm not sure why it doesn't work here.

Answer (score 1):

You can now append `asp-append-version="true"` to a `<script>` or `<link>` tag to solve your problem automatically.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />

<script src="~/js/index.js" type="text/javascript" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

[Short article explaining usage](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/aspappendversion-feature-in-asp-net-core)

[Microsoft Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers.scripttaghelper.appendversion?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Answer (score 0):

---

The best approach is to use the versioning in file name. If you are using code versioning like SVN, Microsoft Team Foundation etc, then you can use the last checkin number as suffix to file name, for example, let say the current checkin number is 1321 (or you can also use time stamp **yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm** ie **2015-01-15-17-15**)

therefore
somefile.js will become **somefile_v1321.js**
or
somefile.js will become **somefile_v2015-01-15-17-15.js**

Now you will wonder there is so much file name change happening here. The answer is, if your releases are very frequent, then consider using scripting language like Ant scripts, which can change the JS and CSS import file names in release files.

### Every time new deployment will take place, the resources will have a new unified path, which will be unique to the browser, so it will do fresh load.