# How do I make sure the user has the latest JS after deployment?

Tags: browser, browser-cache, cdn, cache-control

I have a site with some JavaScript in a .js file.  Let's call it foo.js.  The site is hosted on an Apache server that is fronted by a CDN.

Here are the (hopefully relevant) directives on foo.js from the developer tools in my browser:

```
age: 45777
cache-control: max-age=1209600, must-revalidate
date: Tue, 13 Oct 2020 09:52:11 GMT
last-modified: Tue, 22 Sep 2020 10:58:29 GMT
```

### Questions

1. If I deploy a new version of foo.js to Apache, when will I see the new version in my browser?
2. If the answer is something along the lines of "after max-age has passed", are there directives I can set to tell the browser to check to see if the file has changed, but don't go all the way back to the origin Apache server to check?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elegant way to force client browsers to re-download our asp.net web app's .css and .js files (without totally disabling caching)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17626830/elegant-way-to-force-client-browsers-to-re-download-our-asp-net-web-apps-css-a)

Comment: Not quite.  I want to make sure I understand how setting the max-age and must-revalidate cache-control header affects when the user will get the new version.  I also want to know if there are different directives I can set to get the desired behavior.  Thanks!